# creating a shape file with pyshp

Tags: python-3.x, qgis, pyshp

I have a question and hope someone can help me. I am trying to create a Shape File with Python3. This also works, but if I want to display the file in qgis 2.18.0, I can not zoom into the layer. The shapefile I have created with pyshp. The properties of the file indicate that there are no reference system units. How can I do this with Python? Best regards

Comment: Please show us your code so we can fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, but I found today a solution. I had forgotten to set the bbox settings. After I've added this, everything works. Excuse me for the late reply but yesterday I had a day off